# Good way to find majority in a vector in R?

Tags: r

In a vector in R, if I have  a data likes:

`1  1  2  1  1  3  3  1  1`

In this case, `1` is majority.

Of course, I can loop through a list and count manually, but is there a better way in R to find what is the major value in a vector?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2547402/903061

Answer (score 7):

You can use `table`

```
x <- c(1,1,2,1,1,3,3,1,1)
which.max(table(x))
# 1 
# 1
```

Maybe, something like this would be more helpful.

```
names(which.max(table(x)))
# "1"
```

---

Another option is using `count` function from `plyr` package

```
library(plyr)
df <- count(x)
df[which.max(df$freq),1]
# [1] 1
```

Comment: I don't think that your solution with `x[which.max(table(x))]` works. Try `x <- c(5,5,2,5,5,3,3,5,5)`.

Comment: @RHertel Right. how about using `names` ? See update.

Comment: @RHertel Okk..and I see that you have used `names` already in your answer

Comment: @RonakShah Now it looks good. I hope you don't mind that I posted an answer myself, to discuss in more detail the pitfalls of named integers.

Comment: @RHertel no problem. You have explained it better :)

Answer (score 2):

We could try

```
as.numeric(names(which.max(table(x))))
```

**Example:**

```
x <- c(5,5,2,5,5,3,3,5,5)
#> as.numeric(names(which.max(table(x))))
#[1] 5
```

**Explanation:**

The result of `which.max(table(x))` is a named integer, which in this case is

```
#> which.max(table(x))
#5 
#3
```

Here the value is 3 and the name is "5". This output provides the information that the most frequent entry is the third unique number contained in the vector, counted in ascending order (here the ordered numbers are: 2, 3, and 5) and it has the "name" 5 . In the case of a vector consisting of numbers this naming of a number might look strange, but the vector could as well contain words, like "red", "blue", "green", and then knowing the name of the most frequent word would definitely be useful.

We are only interested in the name, which we can extract with the function `names()`. The result is a character, which in our case can be coerced into an integer using `as.numeric()`.

Answer (score 1):

We could speed up the `table` function using `Rcpp`

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::map<double, int> tableC(NumericVector x) {
std::map<double, int> counts;
int n = x.size();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    counts[x[i]]++;
  }

 return counts;
}
```

Then, we `source` the file,

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp('Table.cpp')
x <- c(1,1,2,1,1,3,3,1,1)
tableC(x)
#1 2 3 
#6 1 2 
which.max(tableC(x))
#1 
#1
```